# Google Cloud Endpoints Object is never Null

Tags: rest, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following cloud endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "test.insert")
public Test insertTest(final Test test)
{
// test is Test here, but not null
}
```

I pass null as parameter on the Android client:

```
api.test().insert(null).execute();
```

On the backend, a Test object is created, where all fields are null. But the object itself is not null.

- How can I test the object for null or prevent null to be passed into the API?

I know I can make @Named parameters @Nullable, but for the object parameter it looks like GCE or REST does not reconstitute null objects as expected.

Comment: did you ever find this out? how to set constraints to the objects we send in the body and their fields?

Comment: We finally gave up on Google Could Endpoints and switched to Spring, best decision we could have ever made. Cloud Endpoints has a lot of sick behavior like you return an empty array on the server and receive null on the client. Don't use it.

Answer (score -1):

Use com.google.api.client.util.Data.isNull method to check the value is null.